# Reading from /dev/serial0 using cat quits working after reading with python program

Tags: serial

Using 2020-12-02-raspios-buster-armhf-lite I have a GPS that outputs TTL connected to the UART pins (pins 4, 6, 8, 10) with serial login disabled.  After first booting up I can see output from the GPS if I cat /dev/serial0 (output masked for privacy).

```
$ cat /dev/serial0 | tr [0-9] X
$GPGSV,X,X,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX*XX

$GPGSV,X,X,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX*XX

$GLGSV,X,X,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,*XE

$GLGSV,X,X,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,,XX,XX,XXX,*XX

$GNGLL,XXXX.XXXXX,N,XXXXX.XXXXX,W,XXXXXX.XX,A,A*XX

^C
```

I can also run a python program to receive output.

```
$ cat gps.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import serial
import re

sp = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', 9600, timeout=1.0)
sp.flushInput()
while True:
    try:
        data = sp.read_until()
        print(re.sub('[0-9]', 'X', data.decode('ascii')))
    except serial.SerialTimeoutException:
        print('Timeout.')
        continue
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupt.')
        break;
print('Exiting...')
sp.close()

$ ./gps.py 
$GPGSV,X,X,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,,XX,XX,XXX,XX*XC

$GPGSV,X,X,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX*XD

$GPGSV,X,X,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX*XX

$GLGSV,X,X,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX*XX

$GLGSV,X,X,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,XX,XX,XX,XXX,*XX

^CInterrupt.
Exiting...
```

However, after running the python program I can no longer see output
from cat /dev/serial0.  The command returns immediately and no
output is produced.  I can rerun the python program and see output,
but can no longer see anything from cat /dev/serial0 until I reboot.
Can someone tell me why that is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to split data stream from one serial port (ttyAMA0) to multiple virtual ports in Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106221/is-there-a-way-to-split-data-stream-from-one-serial-port-ttyama0-to-multiple-v)

Answer (score 1):

So I found out if I reset the terminal line settings after I run the
python program I can then cat from /dev/serial0 again.  So the sequence
is:

```
$ cat /dev/serial0
$ ./gps.py 
$ stty -F /dev/serial0 sane
$ cat /dev/serial0
```

Not sure how to get pySerial to reset things for me before I exit the python program.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `close()` function is hanging for some reason, so you are not able to read via `cat` because the port is not closed properly.
Try adding the followings to make sure that is not happening:

```
import time

sp.reset_input_buffer()
time.sleep(0.3)
sp.reset_output_buffer()
time.sleep(0.3)
sp.close()
```

So what you are doing is basically flushing buffers, which is mostly recommended for these kind of uses. You might also want to check [Pyserial API documentation](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html) for further information.